# Is there a theory about art as a perception(way to "see" things?)

Tags: aesthetics, art

Art as a perception as in looking at an object,environment,experience in a **thoughtful and slow way ,"appreciating" it**,thus letting an object become art.

Comment: Afaic this is a relevant question but these one-liners tend to get closed out  here. The answers [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/64744/37256) may give you direction to flesh it out. I suggest you expand it with context to a few paragraphs at least

Comment: The idea of art as perception was popular in the early 20th century. Italian philosopher Croce developed it in Estetica (1902), see [History as Thought and Action by Peters](https://books.google.com/books?id=q7u7BAAAQBAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s). From different perspectives so did painter [Fry (1909)](http://theoria.art-zoo.com/an-essay-in-aesthetics-roger-fry/) and Vygotsky, a prominent Soviet psychologist, in his book Psychology of Art (1925), see [excerpt here](https://www.marxists.org/archive/vygotsky/works/1925/art2.htm), and [Lima's commentary](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3195754).

Comment: @existingtags All that perception can do is allow you to understand a piece of art. Perception can't turn something into art. Broadly, art is defined as "*a. The conscious use of the imagination **in the production of objects intended to be contemplated or appreciated as beautiful**, as in the arrangement of forms, sounds, or words*". Obviously, an artist may use their perception to assess the artistic potential of things. Maybe you could modify your question accordingly ...

Comment: there's the russian formalist idea of [defamiliarization](https://literariness.org/2016/03/17/defamiliarization/) which there's a lot to read around (google it)... more contemporary analyses could work with merleau-ponty and phenomenology. they may -- or may not -- bear out your claim

Comment: i mean it's fine to have these intuitions as starting points! but, as a question, it woud be better to show some research effort and / or insight, esp given helpful comments

Comment: Arthur Danto, philosopher, What Art Is. https://www.artinamericamagazine.com/news-features/news/the-artness-of-art-arthur-dantos-what-art-is/

Comment: “ The philosophy of art, on the other hand, is an inquiry into what distinguishes art objects from other things in the world; it is an attempt to answer the question, what makes art art?” Danto see reference to his book above. Libraries should have the book.

Comment: @Gordon good one, thanks